# Why isn't my form rendering on the homepage

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates

Trying to render my form on this homepage div:

```
<div class="col-5">
        {% include "home/form.html" %}
</div>
```

This is my form.html:

```
<h1>Contact Us</h1>
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p}}
    <div class="form-actions">
      <button type="submit">Send</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

views.py:

```
def home(request): 
   
    return render(request, "home/home.html")
    
def contactView(request): 
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = ContactForm()
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['admin@example.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, "home/form.html",{'form':form})

def successView(request):
    return HttpResponse('Success! Thank you for your message.')
```

It works fine when I combine contactView and home into one and render it on home.html.

thanks

Comment: You did not pass any variable named `form` in your `return render(request, 'home/home.html')`. The fact that there is some view that passes a `form` to a `home/form.html`, does not matter.

Comment: but since I am including form.html in home.html, shouldn't it be visible in home.html? so do you suggest to put it all in one view?

Comment: no it simply means you also render the `form.html`, but with the same variables you passed to the root template. A view has nothing to do with templates and vice versa. A view can render zero, one, or more templates (not per se to the response), and a template can be included in zero, one or more views.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable "form" is just initiated within the if/else and is therefore not undefined in the context. One solution is to use ContactForm() as default and it will be overriden if it is a post request.

```
def contactView(request): 
    form = ContactForm()
    
    else:
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            subject = form.cleaned_data['subject']
            from_email = form.cleaned_data['from_email']
            message = form.cleaned_data['message']
            try:
                send_mail(subject, message, from_email, ['admin@example.com'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, "home/form.html",{'form':form})
```